# Good reference for doing hierarchcial linear modeling in R

Tags: regression, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

Is there a good reference for conducting hierarchical linear modeling in R, in best case with a good mix between theory and application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start is Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models.* It addresses a wide range of regression models, including hierarchical models.

Gelman et al cover hierarchical models from a Bayesian perspective in *Bayesian Data Analysis* (3rd ed.), but this might be best read second, since it assumes a high level of familiarity with frequentist methods.